# Expo Start opens Webpack server automatically instead of opening in expo App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to open my app inside the expo App. However, when expo starts it opens up the web pack servers instead of leading me to safari inside my Phone 11 simulator. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Dependencies below:

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.5",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suffered from the same problem,it is happening because i used npm install @react-navigation/native to install navigation.uninstall the navigation(npm uninstall @react-navigation/native) and Use yarn add @react-navigation/native to install.

Delete .expo folder before running npm start. Run npm start -c which will clear the caches. Also delete the web-build folder if exits. This solves the problem!

This error might be possibly due to unlinking of the dependencies by NPM while yarn does it.

Comment: Had the same issues and this helped resolved it, is there a reason why it causes expo to open a web pack server? Does npm install web pack components along with the react-navigation package?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to happen arbitrarily and it happens usually after installing a package using NPM. When this happens, I uninstall the package, then re-install it using YARN.

I suggest installing packages separately, so you can identify which package is causing this issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused whenever you install any expo package using npm. So follow the below steps:

1. uninstall any recent package that you have installed using npm via
   `npm uninstall --save "package-name"` command
2. delete the `.expo`, `.expo-shared` and `web-build` folder from your directory
3. clear the cache using `npm start -c` command
4. install any package using `yarn` or `expo` command